# Error while installing the Cocoapods in macOS

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I have **macOS BigSur version 11.7.10** and **Xcode version 13.2.1** and **ruby version 2.6.10p210** and **flutter version 3.7.0** , **Dart 2.19.0**, **DevTools 2.20.1**

when I tried to run this `sudo gem install cocoapods` or `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.11.3`

it gives me below error

```
imacpro1@192 ~ % sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.11.3
Password:
Fetching cocoapods-downloader-1.6.3.gem
Fetching cocoapods-core-1.11.3.gem
Fetching zeitwerk-2.6.12.gem
Fetching activesupport-6.1.7.6.gem
Fetching cocoapods-1.11.3.gem
Successfully installed cocoapods-downloader-1.6.3
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

  current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20231205-636-1vxfozq.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in `block in try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in `try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:672:in `try_ldflags'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1832:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:9:in `system_libffi_usable?'
    from extconf.rb:46:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/ffi-1.16.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/ffi-1.16.3/gem_make.out
imacpro1@192 ~ %
```

I want to install Cocoapods because when I try to run my flutter project it gives me

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.
```

I have tried many solutions like install through **brew**, started **command line tools**.
also I have tried **open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app**

Answer (score 0):

Use:

gem sources --add http://rubygems.org/

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn] [YES]

then use:

gem install sass

and done

I hope this will help you.

Comment: imacpro1@192 ~ % gem install sass
Fetching sass-listen-4.0.0.gem
Fetching rb-inotify-0.10.1.gem
Fetching rb-fsevent-0.11.2.gem
Fetching sass-3.7.4.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
imacpro1@192 ~ %

Comment: If you don't want to run sudo then install ruby using homebrew

brew install ruby
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
gem install rails
You may want to add export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem" to your ~/.bash_profile or .zshrc if you're using zsh

Note: RubyGems keeps old versions of gems, so feel free to do some cleaning after updating:

gem cleanup

Comment: if this not help you check this link.   https://www.rubyonmac.dev/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-6-0-directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
flutter clean
rm -rf ios/Pods
rm -rf ios/.symlinks
rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock
rm -rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: imacpro1@192 doctorapp % cd iOS      

imacpro1@192 ios % arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update.      

arch: Can't find pod in PATH

Comment: pod install --repo-update

Comment: zsh: command not found: pod

Comment: https://medium.com/@staceypyee/installing-cocoapods-on-m1-macbook-air-big-sur-fefccd23f701

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps :

1. Install homebrew using terminal. Copy below line and paste in terminal and press enter

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

2. Install cocoapods using brew. Just run below line in terminal

brew install cocoapods

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: Already tried not working.....